# Set value of radiobutton Angular

Tags: angular, radio-button

I'm trying to bind radiobutton to data this ways but no radio button is checked:

```
<div class="row data-row" *ngFor="let component of data">
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                           <input type="radio" id="radio_true_{{component.crmField}}" name="{{component.crmField}}"  [value]="1" [checked]="component.value === 1"> Yes
                           <input type="radio" id="radio_false_{{component.crmField}}" name="{{component.crmField}}" [value]="0" [checked]="component.value === 0"> No
   </div></div>
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I reproduced in stackblitz and it works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xxegsd?file=src/app/app.component.ts, are you sure component.value is equal to 1? You may want to show where you instantiate `data`.

Comment: I suggest reemplace the `[checked]=..` by a `[(ngModel)]="component.value"`